# Apply a CSS rule to only one HTML table?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, selector

I have 2 tables on a single html page.

I would like to remove the border on just one of them.

The css I have currently is...

```
.table th, .table td {
     border-top: none !important;
 }
```

this is also linked with the table (I have bootstrap on it also, I think the table class is also linked with that?)

```
<table class="table">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <th>1</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>1</td>
    </tr> etc.....
```

So in the CSS I just want to make a rule that applies no border to only one of the 2 tables on my page. However I can't figure out how to to do it because the are using the same table class, and not sure if I need more than one rule? I've tried using parent selectors and ID selectors but could be calling them wrong. Thanks everyone!

Comment: just remove the classname from the table that you don't want the border on

Comment: Please start by learning CSS... http://htmldog.com/guides/css/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could just add a unique class or id to whichever table you *do* want to style and target that selector in your CSS. Like so:

#### HTML

```
<table class="table unique-name">
  ...whatever contents
</table>
```

#### CSS

```
.unique-name {
  // some styles.
}
```

---

#### UPDATE

Here's a [Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/f3c25ob7/1/) to show you what I'm talking about.

Notice that the table with the class `styled-table` assigned to it has some formatting, while the table with the class `unstyled-table` has no formatting.

Comment: yes thank you this is what im trying, however I think the problem is that in order to make something a table I have to use the "table class" so `<table class="table noborder">` is still tied to both of them and it is applying the rule correctly but to both of them even with a noborder "class" added. any ideas? thanks!

Comment: @BenjaminCasalino you don't have to use the `table` class to make something a table. You may have some particular table-specific styling connected to the `table` class, but the `table` *tag* (i.e. `<table>`) is what makes it a table. If you want to use a particular class with only one table, only assign the class to that particular table. I'll add a Fiddle to my answer to show you what I mean.

Answer (score 2):

One way to do it would be to add another class to table you want to remove the border from.

Something like `<table class="table noborder">` and then apply whatever css you want to the `noborder` class.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way would be to have styles on the table, and then modify the table accordingly.  This would be an example of how:

```css
.table--bordered {
  border: 1px solid #666;
}
```

```html
<table class="table">
  // No Borders
</table>

<table class="table table--bordered">
  // With Borders
</table>
```

Comment: `.no_border, .table th, .table td   {
    border-top: none !important;
    background-color: red;
}`
`<table class="table no_border">`

thanks its def working but applying it to all the tables not just the one i need. I also tried `<table id="noBorder" class="table"> etc...#noBorder`

Answer (score 0):

Bootstrap class for bordered table is `table-bordered`. If you don't use it, there'll be no border on table.